# AWS - Internet Access for an EC2 Proxy to Serverless Aurora in a Private Subnet with NAT Gateway (Accessed by Lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance I use as an SSH proxy to my Aurora SERVERLESS instance. I also have lambdas that access this Aurora DB. Finally I have setup the Lambdas (and subsequently pulled in the Aurora DB) into a private subnet and setup NAT Gateway to a public subnet with an Internet Gateway setup for internet access. This was required so that my lambdas can talk to AWS's Pinpoint.

Before I setup all the private subnets for the Pinpoint access from the lambdas I could access my EC2 publicly (from my computer) and connect to my Aurora DB through an SSH connection as a proxy. That was all good. But now it's not accessible.

I believe the public IP of the EC2 is no longer accessible (it doesn't ping) or perhaps it's something else. But what do I need to setup in order that I can access the EC2 publicly again? I thought about setting up port forwarding through the internet gateway/nat gateway but after looking into that it seemed quite complicated. Is there some sort of subnet, setup I should be putting my EC2 in to make things work?

Answer (score 2):

> But what do I need to setup in order that I can access the EC2 publicly again?

Put it back in a public subnet. That's the entire point of a public subnet - to be able to access your resources from the internet.

You could also increase its security by using [SSH tunnel through AWS Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/systems-manager-ssh-vpc-resources/).

Comment: The problem is that then it won't be able to access the Aurora Serverless instance as it's in the same private subnets as the lambdas that also need to access it. The lambdas must be in the private subnets.

Comment: @Etep An instance in a public subnet, can access resources in a private subnet.

Comment: I guess that's the issue. I have the EC2 in the same subnet as the RDS. But I can't talk to it (from public internet). (obvious, it's in the private). But I also can't seem to move the EC2 to another subnet (ie a public one). Is my only option then to delete the EC2 and create a new one in the public subnet? What's confusing also is that the EC2 has a private and a public IP. This worked when the Internet Gateway (IG) was in the subnet but now the IG is in the public subnet and the private has a NAT Gateway.  I wasn't able to add a new IG to the private. Which makes sense, still confusing.

Comment: @Etep I think the bigger issue is why you can't connect to your RDS from the instance? To answer that you have to provide all the details of your setup.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I can't connect to the EC2 instance (remotely). I believe the EC2 can still connect to the RDS. But I can't confirm that until I get into the EC2.

Comment: The solution was to "move" the EC2 to the public subnet. This required making a new EC2 because you aren't allowed to move an existing one. That then led to some other issues with then getting an elastic IP allocated properly and having a second interface for internal purposes on the private subnet. I did that because I didn't want to be communicating to my RDS over public IPs. Regardless I got it working. I can post a detailed solution as an answer but that seems a bit self serving here for SO points.

Comment: @Etep Glad it worked out. Acceptance of my answer would be appreciated if it helped.